# What's the meaning of plain string when using as condition?

Tags: perl

Below perl one-liner outputs hello to console, so how is false interpreted here since it is not a variable or literal string?

```
perl -e"if (false) {print 'hello'}"
```

Comment: `use warnings;` or `perl -we "if (false) {print 'hello'}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html

> Barewords
>
> A word that has no other interpretation in the grammar will be treated
>   as if it were a quoted string. These are known as "barewords".

Answer (score 5):

In Perl false is true. The only terms that are evaluated as false are:

```
0, '0', '', (), (''), undef
```

FALSE/TRUE are not boolean values. They are called barewords and with `use strict;`, it will not even run.